# Searching a TreeMap by a member of the value class using lambda expressions

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a question related to lambda expressions in Java 8.

Consider the following `Message` class :

```
  public class Message implements MessageBase 
  {  
      private String id;
      private String message;
      private String author;
      private Long timestamp;

      public Message()
      {
          this.id=null;
          this.message=null;
          this.author=null;
          this.timestamp= null;
      }

      public Message(String id, String message,String author,Long timestamp)
      {
          this.id=id;
          this.message=message;
          this.author=author;
          this.timestamp= timestamp;
      }

      public String getId() 
      {
          return id;
      }

      public void setId(String id) 
      {
          this.id = id;
      }

      public String getMessage() 
      {
          return message;
      }

      public void setMessage(String message) 
      {
          this.message = message;
      }

      public String getAuthor() 
      {
          return author;
      }

      public void setAuthor(String author) 
      {
          this.author = author;
      }

      public long getTimestamp() 
      {
          return timestamp;
      }

      public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) 
      {
          this.timestamp = timestamp;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) 
      {
          if (this == o) 
              return true;
          if (!(o instanceof Message)) 
              return false;

          Message message1 = (Message) o;

          if (getTimestamp() != message1.getTimestamp()) 
              return false;
          if (!getId().equals(message1.getId())) 
              return false;
          if (!getMessage().equals(message1.getMessage())) 
              return false;
          return getAuthor().equals(message1.getAuthor());
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() 
      {
          int result = getId().hashCode();
          result = 31 * result + getMessage().hashCode();
          result = 31 * result + getAuthor().hashCode();
          result = 31 * result + (int) (getTimestamp() ^ (getTimestamp() >>> 32));
          return result;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() 
      {
          return "id=" + id +
                  ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                  ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                  ", timestamp=" + timestamp;
      }
```

which implements the `MessageBase` interface. I store objects of the `Message` class in a `TreeMap` - `Map<Long, Message> messages`. The key is a timestamp and the value is a `Message` object. I have to find all `TreeMap` entries by author, which is a field of the `Message` class. I'm trying to do this using lambda expressions.

Here is my code:

```
messages.entrySet().stream().filter(o->o.getValue().getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(author)).findAny();
```

Using this code I can get only one entry. Can you help me get a list of all the entries that pass the filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`findAny` returns at most one entry. You should collect the Stream into a `Collection` or a `Map` to get all the entries :

```
Map<Long, Message> filteredMessages =   
    messages.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(o->o.getValue().getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(author))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

or

```
List<Map.Entry<Long, Message>> filteredMessages =   
    messages.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(o->o.getValue().getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(author))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to group all the `Message` instances by author:

```
Map<String, List<Message>> byAuthor = messages.values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Message::getAuthor));
```

This will create a list of messages for every author.

If you also need the key of the original map to be grouped by author, you could use an overloaded version of the `groupingBy()` method, which will allow you to preserve the original entries:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, Message>> byAuthor = messages.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e.getValue().getAuthor(),
        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Here a map of maps is being created, and the entries are streamed (instead of just the values, as in the first example). The first map is grouping by author, while the second map is a submap of the original map that contains only the entries that match the corresponding author.